# What to add in settings.xml/pom.xml for apache archiva to work

Tags: apache, maven

** Apparently no one out there knows how to make this work.  **

I have uploaded five jar files to apache archiva.  The console is running and I can browse and see the, "pom snippet".

I have tried to add apache archiva information to my settings.xml:

```
<mirrors>
    <mirror>
        <id>Official1</id>
        <url>http://repo1.maven.org/maven2</url>
        <mirrorOf>central</mirrorOf>
    </mirror>
    <mirror>
        <id>apache archiva</id>
        <url>http://172.##.##.##:8080</url>
        <mirrorOf></mirrorOf>
    </mirror>
```

And then added the snippet to my pom.xml file (last dependency in the list):

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
        <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
        <version>6.9.10</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.relevantcodes</groupId>
        <artifactId>extentreports</artifactId>
        <version>2.41.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
        <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
        <version>3.14</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
        <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
        <version>3.14</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
       <groupId>GroupFromApacheArchiva</groupId>
       <artifactId>DatabaseDriver</artifactId>
       <version>5.73</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

I then save everything and build but Maven can't resolve the newly added dependency.

What am I doing incorrectly?

When I pull out the apache archiva from the settings.xml and the GroupFromApacheArchiva from the pom.xml everything builds and runs normally.

Comment: You are adding it as additional repository.  Have you tried using it in <repository> tag in maven itself?  - http://archiva.apache.org/docs/1.4-M4/userguide/using-repository.html#

Comment: @niharika_neo to be honest the whole thing really confuses me.  I've been trying to figure out the documentation on that webpage for a while but I'm still uncertain. I wish there were some more examples.

Comment: How does this work?  I already have a mirror and a proxy specified in the settings.xml file.  If I create a profile do I need to move everything inside of that profile?  Even the mirror and proxy information?  Will my project still be able to get out to see the mvnrepository?